# Do not show earlier dates using UIDatePicker

Tags: swift, nsdate, uidatepicker

I have my UIDatePicker setup to so the minimum day/time is today/right.  Code is simply as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
datePicker.minimumDate = NSDate()
```

However, in the app earlier dates still appear to the user before today in the "wheel".  When the user tries to select them it's not allowed and the wheel goes back to today's date.  Not sleek from a UI stand point.

Is it possible to not have those earlier dates show up using UIDatePicker?  If not, what other method would you use?  Perhaps a custom UIPickerView?

Open Table is one app that has this day/time solved, but I'm not sure how they are doing it.  Thanks!

Comment: I guess it's not possible?  Any general ideas even if you don't have the exact answer?